# check if string contains a number

Tags: jquery

I need to use jquery 1.3.2 and would like to check if a string inside element contains a number. If not an alert should popup.
Here is my code but it does not work. What is wrong with it? thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var val = $(".xxx").val();   
var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches != null) {
alert('number');
} 
});
```

html

```
<div class="xxx">aaa</div>
```

Comment: The element doesn't contain a number ?

Comment: Also the element has no value, it's a **DIV**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.html()` or `.text()`, not `.val()`. `.val()` is for input elements:

```
var val = $(".xxx").html();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9EZy4/)**